# How can I describe the union between this specific set and the Fibonacci sequence set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, fibonacci-numbers

I have two sets, $M_1$ and $M_2$:

$$
M_1 = \{x\mid x \text{ is a Fibonacci number}\}\\
M_2 = \{x \mid  −10 \leq x \leq 10\}
$$
How can I describe the union between these sets?

$$M_1 \cup M_2$$

Thanks.

Comment: [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) are non negative integers. Thus if $x \text { is a Fibonacci number}$ is good, you have : $M_1 \cup M_2 = \{ x \mid (-10 \le x \le 10) \text { or } x \text { is a Fibonacci number } \}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A,B$ are sets, then $A \cup B$ is the set of all elements of $A$ or $B$. In other words, $M_1 \cup M_2$ is the set of all Fibonacci numbers together with integers in $[-10,10]$.